# Inductive proof for recursive formula with multiple recursive references

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction, recurrence-relations, recursion

This one is hard for me due to multiple recursive statements in the definition, and I have difficulty with inequalities.

$a_1=1$

$a_2=1$

$a_3=1$

$a_{n+3} = a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}+a_n$

**Prove** that for each natural number n with n>1: $a_n≤2^{n-2}$

Might be helpful for reference: $a_4=3, a_5=5,a_6=9, a_7=17$

When trying to prove P(n+1) I got: an+1=an+an−1+an−2=2n−2+2n−3+2n−4 which according to Wolfram Alpha is 7∗2n−4 though I don't know how that is reached. From there, I don't really know how to prove that

Comment: Use induction. It's smooth.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg When trying to prove P(n+1) I got:
$a_{n+1} = a_n+a{n-1}+a{n-2} = 2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}+2^{n-4}$ which according to Wolfram Alpha is $7*2^{n-4}$ though I don't know how that is reached. 
From there, I don't really know how to prove that $7*2^{n-4} ≤ 2^{n-1}$

Comment: $8*2^{n-4} = 2^3*2^{n-4}$ should get you to the end. And we got $7*2^{n-4}$ from $a_{n-2} \leq 2^{n-4}$, $a_{n-1} \leq 2^{n-3}$, and $a_n \leq 2^{n-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The base is obvious.

Let $a_k\leq2^{k-2}$ for all $3\leq k\leq n$.

Thus,
$$a_{k+1}=a_k+a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}\leq2^{k-2}+2^{k-3}+2^{k-4}=7\cdot2^{k-4}<8\cdot2^{k-4}=2^{k-1}$$
and we are done!